# Can I don level 65 pvp armor without being level 65 by using this trick?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Can I wear the armor by: having a level 65 person buy them and then mail it to me. Then during the pvp match (everyone is shifted to level 65) I don the gear? Will it stay on me or is there a flaw in the plan?

Comment: Sounds like an awfully easy thing to test.

Comment: You need to buy the gear and to buy it you must be level 65 and to do that you need to pay money.

Answer (score 1):

Two flaws:

1:  The Level Shift (in either directly) **will not affect the restriction on gear to wear**.  When you get level shifted upwards (So from Lv10 to Lv65), the gear still checks it's requirements against your base character level.  This is to make sure that a Lv35 character in a Lv16 zone can still get and equip gear at Lv35~, but a Lv20 character boosted to Lv65 for a Flash Point won't be able to suddenly equip a level 22 item.

2: The PVP gear can have it's mods removed, but it will not remove the bind to character when bought.

There is PVP gear you can buy that's Lv65 and Bind on Equip, but it's usually without mods as the entire piece is crafted.  Likewise, the same issue comes up here with that PVP gear not being useable until you hit the level requirement first.